# Remove word endings if contained in a specific list of endings

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

The problem I am dealing with is that I need to remove the word ending if that ending is in a specific list.

i.e suppose the list is:

```
{ical, ic,ion,ogy} //the actual list is a handful of elements (almost ~20)
```

What I need to do is, when I come across a sentence like such:

```
Hello world, this sentence is magic. Because we will talk about Biology.
```

It will be reduced to:

```
Hello world, this sentence is **mag** . Because we will talk about **Biol** .
```

The simplest way to do this would be to iterate through the Words in a sentence, and check if each ending matches a element in the list...but this is VERY expensive.

Is there a simpler way to achieve above?

***** ALSO *****

You could do this with a single large REGEX:

```
(?<=([a-zA-Z]))(ic|ical|ics|raphy|raphic|raphical|ion|ions|ional|ive|ivity|ity|ities|ische|ischen|ischer|isches|ogy|ogic|ogical|omy|omic|omics|omical)(?=(\b))
```

Comment: How big will your sentence be? Performance shouldn't be too bad if your endings list contains only ~20 elements.

Comment: Network I/O operations, esp. database queries, are -very- expensive.  The operation you describe is likely to be slightly expensive by comparison.  It is a result you may wish to cache, if it is needed several times ... but in any case, I do not think there is a more efficient algorithm to solving your problem than the one you're proposing.

Comment: In any case it seems at least less expensive than matching almost 20 endings with regex...

Comment: Have you profiled it? Is it really very expensive? Show some code how you actually solve your problem. There lots of ways.

Comment: You don't need to look-ahead in your regex - `\b` doesn't indicate an actual character (similarly to `^` and `$`), so not using look-ahead here doesn't change much.

Comment: And you probably need no lookbehind. Maybe `\B` (not word boundary) at the beginning would do (it would unless you need to exclude things like "5ic"). It mighty be slower or faster or the same, depending on the implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The simple approach:**

Build a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) of the input strings and replace all occurrences of that regex with nothing.

The regex will be in the form:

```
(a|b|c)\\b
```

`(a|b|c)` matches `a`, `b` or `c`.
`\\b` is a word boundary, indicating the end of a word.

Code:

```
String[] arr = {"ical", "ic", "ion", "ogy"};
String input = "Hello world, this sentence is magic. Because we will talk about Biology.";
String regex = "(" + arr[0];
for (String s: arr)
   regex += "|" + s; // using Pattern.quote(s) instead of s here would be safer
regex += ")\\b";
input = input.replaceAll(regex, "");
System.out.println(input);
```

Prints:

```
Hello world, this sentence is mag. Because we will talk about Biol.
```

**The rather more complicated approach:**

Build a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) of your suffixes, but **in reverse**.

Process the string from the back.

If you get the start of a word, look through the trie for the next characters, cutting them off if you find a match in the trie.

Use a `StringBuilder` and `StringBuilder.reverse()` at the end to do this efficiently.

**Example:**

Given:

```
ical, ic, ion, ogy
```

Your trie will look like:

```
          .
         /|\
      y // \\ l
       /n| |c\
      .  . .  .
     g| o| |i |a
      .  . X  .
     o| i|    |c
      X  X    .
              |i
              X
```

(`X` is a terminating node (the end of a suffix), `.` is a non-terminating node)

Input:

```
John Biology.
```

Processing in reverse...

Process: `"."`

Not a word, just add to output.

Output = `"."`

Process: `"Biology"`

The root has a `y` child, so we move to that node.
That node has a `g` child, so we move on.
That node has an `o` child, so we move on.
Then we've reached a terminating node, so discard the processed characters and print the rest of the word.

Output: `".loiB"`

Process: `" "`

Not a word, just add to output.

Output = `".loiB "`

Process: `"John"`

The root has an `n` child, so we move to that node.
That node doesn't have an `h` child, so we stop and output the processed characters along with the rest of the word (i.e. output the whole word).

Output = `".loiB nhoJ"`

Reverse, giving us: `"John Biol."`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is more efficient than looping (I suspect it is), but why not use a regular expression with replaceAll() to strip the words of their endings.

The \b tag makes sure that only word endings are caught.

```
public class TestRegEx {

public static final String SENTENCE = "Hello world, this sentence is magic. Because we will talk about Biology. Physical. Reunion.";
public static final String PATTERN = "(ic|ogy|ical|ion)\\b";

public static void main(String[] args) {

     System.out.println(SENTENCE.replaceAll(PATTERN, ""));
    }
}
```

The output I get from this is:

Hello world, this sentence is mag. Because we will talk about Biol. Phys. Reun.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limited number of endings you want to check you can generate a regex for each of them. This should allow efficient checks if the ending occurs, you don't need to split the sentence and can do the replacement in a single line.

Sadly my java Regex knowlege isn't good enough that I can build the required regex on the fly, but you can have a look at. But there are many [good tutorials out there](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).

Comment: Since this answer is just pointing OP in the right direction, rather than answering the question, it may have been better suited as a comment.